# How do I search between two date ranges in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have hit a stumbling block and could just do with some assistance please.

I have been tasked with creating a VBA Macro that looks between two date ranges in a shared inbox sub-folder in Outlook.

If the code finds any Excel documents attached to the emails within that date range it will extract the attachments and will put them into a designated shared drive folder. All of this i had working perfectly, however, I now need to change the code slightly so that on a separate sheet it adds the date the code was last ran (this I have working also) and when the code is next ran it takes the date it last ran as the "Date from" date and searches between that date and whatever the date and time is of the time you are trying to execute the code again - this is where my code isn't working.

Here is my code so far (I am not a VBA expert and some terminology may not be correct so please go easy on my code) - I have had to replace certain sensitive info with "xxxxxx" in the code below.

```
Sub saveOutlookAttachments()

    ' For this to work, you need to ensure "Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library" is ticked
    ' You can find the object library in Tools -> References

    ' -- start of initialise all the outlook library details needed
    Dim ol As Outlook.Application
    Dim ns As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim fol As Outlook.Folder
    Dim i As Object
    Dim mi As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim at As Outlook.attachment
    Dim Folder As MAPIFolder
    Dim OutlookMail As Variant
    
    ' -- end of initialise all the outlook library details needed
    
    ' -- start of Date from and to initialising
    
    Dim DateStart As Date
    Dim DateEnd As Date
    Dim DateToCheck As String
    
    
        ' Get the date last ran
        If Sheet2.Cells(1, 2) <> "" Then
            Sheet1.Cells(2, 2) = Sheet2.Cells(1, 2)
            Debug.Print "Start Date is: "; Sheet1.Cells(2, 2)
            Sheet1.Cells(2, 4) = Now()
            Debug.Print "End Date is: "; Sheet1.Cells(2, 4)
        Else
            Sheet2.Cells(1, 2) = ""
            Debug.Print Sheet1.Cells(2, 2)
        End If
        
    DateStart = Sheet1.Cells(2, 2) ' Cell B2
    DateEnd = Sheet1.Cells(2, 4) ' Cell B4
    DateToCheck = "[ReceivedTime] >= """ & DateStart & """ And [ReceivedTime] <= """ & DateEnd & """"
    Debug.Print "Date to Check is: "; DateToCheck
    ' -- end of Date from and to initialising
    
    ' -- start of Set ol and Set ns
    
    Set ol = New Outlook.Application
    Set ns = ol.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    
    ' -- end of Set ol and Set ns
    
    ' Which folder should the script be reading from?
    Set fol = ns.Folders("~ xxxxxxx ").Folders("Inbox").Folders("xxxxxxxx")

    ' if there is an error when the code runs then stop the script and go straight to "errordetails" found at the bottom of the screen
    On Error GoTo errordetails
    
    ' For each email in the folder (Restricted to the date range entered on the Spreadsheet)
    For Each i In fol.Items.Restrict(DateToCheck)

    ' If the email is an Outlook email
        If i.Class = OlMail Then

            Set mi = i
                UserForm1.Show
            ' If there are more than 0 attachments, ie, if it finds an attachment
                If mi.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
                
                
                    For Each at In mi.Attachments
                    'Debug.Print mi.SenderName & " " & mi.ReceivedTime ' <- uncomment this part if you need to debug (remember to open the "immediate" window also
                        ' Look for attachments that contain ".xls" (this will also pick up ".xlsx" and ".xlsm" etc
                        If InStr(LCase(at.FileName), ".xls") > 0 Then
                            ' Tell the script where to save the file and what details need to be appeneded to the file name to make it a unique name
                            at.SaveAsFile "\\xxxx\xxxxx\xxxxx\" & Format(mi.ReceivedTime, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-nn-ss") & at.FileName
                            
                        Else

                        ' literally do nothing (it's probably not needed but added just in case)

                        End If


                    Next at
                
                End If

        End If
    Next i
           
UserForm1.Hide

    
    CountNumberOfFiles
    
    Sheet2.Cells(1, 1) = "Date last ran was"
    Sheet2.Cells(1, 2) = Now()
    

errordetails:
    Debug.Print "Error number: " & Err.Number _
            & " " & Err.Description;

End Sub

Sub CountNumberOfFiles()

    Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim Path As String
    Dim Count As Integer
    
    FolderPath = "\\xxxx\xxxxxxx\xxxxxxxxx"
    Path = FolderPath & "\*"
    FileName = Dir(Path)
    
    Do While FileName <> ""
        Count = Count + 1
            FileName = Dir()
    Loop
    
    
        MsgBox "Search completed. There are " & Count & " attachments extracted to the folder \\xxxxxx\xxxxxx\xxxx"
    
End Sub
```

In the Immediate window, the Debug.Print for this part does show all the correct dates and times but it says it finds nothing even when there is one item that definitely matches.

```
     ' Get the date last ran
        If Sheet2.Cells(1, 2) <> "" Then
            Sheet1.Cells(2, 2) = Sheet2.Cells(1, 2)
            Debug.Print "Start Date is: "; Sheet1.Cells(2, 2)
            Sheet1.Cells(2, 4) = Now()
            Debug.Print "End Date is: "; Sheet1.Cells(2, 4)
        Else
            Sheet2.Cells(1, 2) = ""
            Debug.Print Sheet1.Cells(2, 2)
        End If
        
    DateStart = Sheet1.Cells(2, 2) ' Cell B2
    DateEnd = Sheet1.Cells(2, 4) ' Cell B4
    DateToCheck = "[ReceivedTime] >= """ & DateStart & """ And [ReceivedTime] <= """ & DateEnd & """"
    Debug.Print "Date to Check is: "; DateToCheck
    ' -- end of Date from and to initialising
```

Thank you in advance for any assistance provided.

Comment: if you want to compare values in a cell you might want to add `.Value` maybe this helps with the comparison?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dates are DateTime, not Text, so create text expressions for the date values:

```
DateToCheck = "[ReceivedTime] >= #" & Format(DateStart, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# And [ReceivedTime] <= #" & Format(DateEnd, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#"
```

**Addendum**:

Looking up the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.find?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5002361) (always highly recommended), it appears that *criteria must be text*:

> Although dates and times are typically stored with a Date format, the
> Find and Restrict methods require that the date and time be converted
> to a string representation. To make sure that the date is formatted as
> Outlook expects, use the Format function. The following example
> creates a filter to find all contacts that have been modified after
> January 15, 1999 at 3:30 P.M.

Example:

```
sFilter = "[LastModificationTime] > '" & Format("1/15/99 3:30pm", "ddddd h:nn AMPM") & "'"
```

So, I guess you filter should read:

```
DateToCheck = "[ReceivedTime] >= '" & Format(DateStart, "ddddd h:nn AMPM") & "' And [ReceivedTime] <= '" & Format(DateEnd, "ddddd h:nn AMPM") & "'"
```

Comment: Hi @Gustav, thank you for replying, i have tried using your solution but it still says it finds zero results even though there is definitely one there

Comment: thank you so much! Your Addendum code worked perfectly. I really appreciate your time spent on helping with this :)